# Adding write.writerow to a Selenium Script resulted in not every row has quotation mark

Tags: python, selenium

so I use this GitHub Repo to mine Youtube comments. https://github.com/dddat1017/Scraping-Youtube-Comments

Then I added the following code so that the result would automatically be stored in a CSV file.

```
    with io.open('filename.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-16") as file:
         writer = csv.writer(file)
         writer.writerow(["Username", "Comment"])
         for username, comment in zip(username_elems, comment_elems):
             writer.writerow([username.text, comment.text])
```

But the in the CSV file **not every row has quotation mark**

Some of the result

```
Ganda Tri Kusuma,"Normal tuh alami, ini normal kok pakek dipandu. Berarti gak normal dong, normalnya maksa."

bapakhaji tumiran,"New normal adalah herd immunity, siap siap wabah g terkendali rumah sakit nyerah kematian semakin banyak."

Dent Baguz,LG ngeprank 

The Voyager,maksudnya gimana ya ? pemerintah aktif membuka tempat2 keramaian kembali tapi dipasang tni polisi supaya tidak ramai ?
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything to be quoted, you'll want to use `QUOTE_ALL` as a flag for your `csv.writer`:

```py
writer = csv.writer(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

The default is csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL which produces valid CSV and uses quotes only where necessary.